Calculate map zoom so a certain amount of square miles is displayed
I am trying to do the following:
I have a map and on top of it I placed a container which is transparent and only has a border. User can select a certain amount of square miles (1, 3, 10, 20) and upon selection a zoom level of the map is adjusted so that selected amount of square miles are shown within the container.
    Future<void> calculateZoomLevel(int miles, int containerSize) async {
        const double equatorLength =
            40075016.686; // Earth's circumference in meters
        const double tileSize = 256; // Tile size at zoom level 1
        // Convert miles to meters
        final double radiusMeters = miles * 1609.34;

        // Calculate the diameter in meters that needs to fit within the container
        final double diameterMeters = radiusMeters * 2;

        // Get the screen density (DPI)
        final double screenDensity = View.of(context).devicePixelRatio;

        // Calculate the diameter in pixels based on container size and density
        final double diameterPixels = containerSize * screenDensity;

        // Calculate zoom level using the formula
        final double zoomLevel =
           log(equatorLength * diameterPixels / (diameterMeters * tileSize)) / ln2;

        // Set the zoom level on the map controller
        await controller.view.setLocation(zoom: zoomLevel.toDouble());
        print('zoom level = $zoomLevel');
        print('miles = $miles');
      }

This is for Flutter app but framework shouldnt be relevant here, I think only calculation needs to be adjusted.

What's the issue you have encountered so far?

@Yrll so the issue is, zoom level I get is not correct. Simply the amount of map I get visible inside the container does not equal to value user selected. For example if user selected 1 square mile - zoom is adjusted however the amount of map visible within the container is around 0.6 square miles.

(For Android w/ Compose -- but it may help you)
One approach would be to construct a LatLngBounds using the extremes of the circle you are trying to show.
Something like
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

val center = LatLng(39.01989245927223, -106.40513089127599)
val radius = 2787.47 // ~ sqrt(3 square miles) in meters <- adjust this to your needs

val boundingBox = with(LatLngBounds.builder()) {
    listOf(0.0, 90.0, 180.0, 270.0).forEach { heading ->
        include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, radius, heading))
    }
    build()
}

LaunchedEffect(true) {
    scope.launch {
        cameraPositionState.animate(
            update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundingBox, 64), // <- could be set to 0 for no padding
            durationMs = 1000
        )
    }
}

